# How to portably go up through directory hierarchy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to search for a file with a particular name, starting from the current working directory and working up through the hierarchy in a a portable way until I reach the root or equivalent.

In e.g. a Linux environment, I know I can do

```
dir = '.'
while File.expand_path(dir) != '/' do
    <check for the file>
    dir = File.join dir, '..'
end
```

...but is there a nicer way that'd work regardless of where the chain of parent directories ends?

Also, refactoring that local variable away would be nice but I haven't come up with a good way yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In virtually all environments, `"cd .."` at the root of a directory tree will be identical to itself. So, if you go up one level but wind up in the *same* directory, you're at the root.

Make that your condition in the `while` loop.

Comment: May be helpful for some people: I had to use Dir.chdir("..") (in rake file used by Jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

> is there a nicer way that'd work regardless of where the chain of parent directories ends?

Where else would the chain of parent directories end other than at the root directory? A drive's directory structure is a tree, or inverted tree if you want to think of it that way. The "root" directory is always the same; It's as low as you can go.

Your code is fine. You could do it alternate ways, but I doubt you'd gain a lot in clarity or simplicity. You might possibly find something faster, but could trade off the other two for a minor difference in speed, and I doubt you'd notice the speed-up.

It's not idiosyncratic Ruby code, i.e., normally we'd use an array and iterate over it somehow but I don't see that practice buying you much in terms of simplicity or cleanliness.

I give you 90% and a silver star. Good job.

---

EDIT:

I like the answer @John Feminella gave. It's a common-sense way to determine when you've hit the root of a drive system and will work cross-platform nicely. I can't think of any system that would give you a randomly changing root designation, so loop until the directory doesn't change any more.

Comment: Yes, it's a tree. But on Windows, will `File.expand_path(dir) == '/'`, ever?